# Matlab - why crossval function inputs a full trained model?

Tags: cross-validation, matlab

The question is regarding the Matlab implementation.
As we can see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationsvm.crossval.html), the `crossval` function expects to receive a **full trained** model. 
For example, my data consist of 100 observations and we would like to build a model that classify each observation to "1" or "-1" using the SVM classifier. So if we like to cross validate we first should fit a classifier for all 100 observations (this results a ClassificationSVM model trained using fitcsvm) and then we input the `crossval` function with it.

What I don't understand is, why Matlab's implementation require to first train the model before cross validating? since the standard CV process trains on each k − 1 subsamples (and don't use the full fitted model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a model that is already trained on the full data, it is a ClassificationSVM object. There is a `crossval` method that you can use to perform cross-validation on it to assess its generalization error.

If you haven't trained a model yet and you want to do cross validation up front, you can use the `'CrossVal'` option to the `fitcsvm` function, and set its value to `'on'`.